# Apache Airflow - BigQuery Operator Issue

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I am using the following library:

```
airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator
```

On the Airflow UI, it throws the following error:

> Broken DAG: [/home/vagrant/airflow/dags/data/gcp_bq_dag.py]
> (setuptools 28.8.0
> (/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages),
> Requirement.parse('setuptools>=34.0.0'), {'google-api-core'})

I have installed the `setuptools` library and the version I have is `49.2.0`.

```
Name: setuptools
Version: 49.2.0
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: zope.deprecation, python-daemon, protobuf, kiwisolver, jsonschema, ipython, google-auth, google-api-core
```

Can you please suggest what is going wrong there?

Comment: Are you using Airflow on-premise or in Cloud Composer?

Comment: I'm using Airflow on-premise

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the error it was showing on the airflow UI seems to be a redherring:

Broken DAG: [/home/vagrant/airflow/dags/data/gcp_bq_dag.py] (setuptools 28.8.0 (/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.5/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=34.0.0'), {'google-api-core'})

The actual issue is that it was missing pandas_gbq package. This was logged in the webserver logs. I've installed pandas_gbq and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a setup issue around your machine and the various environments of execution. It would be worthwhile taking an a more in depth look with someone technical and familiar with your situation.

Based on reading the error alone. And this could be wrong. But, essentially, the two different contexts are discovering a different version of the installed package. This happens quite often with Python and projects. The version of python that Airflow knows about can only find `setuptools` `28.0.0`. That's just incompatible with the requirements of the DAG.

---

### Edit

You might want to try installing the package against the user `pip install --user setuptools`